# Data Protection Act - MS SQL Deleting Data

Tags: sql-server, security, delete-row, sql-delete, data-protection

I have been asked by a supplier to confirm "What plans\systems are in place to ensure data is deleted and purged when no longer required"...this is specifically targetted at user identification data...name, address etc.

I have responded that "We have automated processes that delete data from our MSSQL database on a nightly basis"

> Background - we have SSIS packages that seek obsolete user data based on various criteria and then deletes that data from the database...actually deletes,  it doesn't flag the row as obsolete or similar,  it doesn't copy to another archive table,  it actually deletes from the live database.

Supplier has responded with "We need confirmation that this is completed by simply deleting a row in the database or by some other means?"

My question is - What other means of deleting SQL data should I be considering?  And what do IS officers want me to be doing to delete data if not DELETE FROM Client WHERE ClientID = 987 ?

Answer (score 1):

The other method of dealing with data that must be cleansed of personal information is to leave the record and change any personally identifiable information to blanks or dashes. This leaves the record intact which is preferable if it acts as a foreign key to other tables.  This works best if you are able to mark the record as archived/obsolete.

If you were to do this a log table showing when the action was taken and on what record should keep your Supplier happy.

Comment: Thanks,  this makes sense,  I'd rather stick with our current process of full delete and manage the foreieng key issues as we currently do if I can,  if the supplier pushes back on this I could certainly implement this solution though.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete data, the record is marked as 'ghosted', needing to be actually deleted sometime in the future.  SQL then deletes the data from the database page where the data was located.

You may still have this data downstream in your backups and logs.

When the supplier asks, or actually states with a question mark at the end:

> "We need confirmation that this is completed by simply deleting a row
>   in the database or by some other means?"

I would answer that you delete the row and information is retained in backups for x days/months.  If they have an issue with it, they can clue you into whatever they have in mind that isn't so 'simple'.

Comment: Ok,  great,  that makes sense,  as does Kenvinskys below... 
At present we delete their record and orphan and summarise any links to order data at the same time this is the answer I'd rather go with